# Reuse fragment to create a Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

I have created a Fragment by extending Fragment in the support package(v4).
This view contains a list and a button. 
My application supports both phone and 10" Tablet. In Phone I use the fragment to display it as a normal screen using Activity
In Tab I need to display the same view as a dialog. Will i be able to reuse the fragment for showing a Dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that depends on if you just want the layout, or if you want the logic behind it. You can use the same layout in a dialog but the logic is generally implemented differently because dialogs are simpler and use basic implementations to things like ok/cancel. They have access to views in the dialog but there isn't a great place for inserting a fragment.

There is a separate class called DialogFragment referenced here:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

It says "the showDialog / dismissDialog methods in Activity are being deprecated in favor of DialogFragments"

Comment: I need bot the layout and the logic. The requirement is in phones, the view should be a normal Activity. And in tablets, the same screen should appear as a dialog. If i use DialogFragments, i will not be able to use it in phones as a normal view

Comment: Well, DialogFragment extends Fragment. I wonder if you could create what you want in a DialogFragment, and then reuse it as a Fragment instead of the other way around.

Comment: Yea. I used the fragment extending DialogFragment. I could use that as a dialog in tablets and embedded on screen in phones